# Trying to run application which uses Oracle libraries on Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, oracle, visual-studio-2005, occi

I am trying to run existing application which uses OCCI libraries - for example in `Linker->Input` the project has specified `oraocci10.lib`.

I am using Visual Studio 2005.

**This is what I did.**

1. Downloaded **10.2.0.5** package from here(1st and 5th packages):

   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html
2. Set environment variables (I have Oracle client installed as it seems):

   ORACLE_HOME
   C:\app\g\product\11.2.0\client_2

   TNS_ADMIN
   C:\app\g\product\11.2.0\client_2\Network\Admin
3. Set paths to oracle libraries in my project:

   *C/C++->General->Include directories:
   D:\instantclient_10_2\sdk\include*

   *Linker->Additional Library directories:
   D:\instantclient_10_2\sdk\lib\msvc*
4. In Code Generation->Runtime Library: Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)

My application compiles but I get run time errors.
When I run this application as a standalone exe (without compiling the executable, I was given that exe separately also) it works fine, connects with the database, etc.

So something must be wrong how I configured Visual Studio against these OCCI libraries. I would really appreciate some help where I have gone wrong, as I am nearing point where I can't guess what I have done wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If what you wrote in your question is accurate, your versions of Instant Client and the OCCI client do not match, and they **have to**. So either you're using 10.2.0.2 or 11.2.0.2, but you can't mix and match. You will tear your hair out trying to get this to work otherwise.